# How to compare strings where a symbol equals more then one value. Javascript

Tags: javascript

So the issue is that I have 2 strings. One string is a random assortment of letters. The second is either a +,*,$ or {N}.  Where the + sign represents all 26 letters, the $ represents numbers 1-9, the asterisk represents any 3 repeating characters unless show differently by {N}.

example: 
input: "+++++*" "abcdehhhhhh"
output: false

input: "$**+*{2}" "9mmmrrrkbb"
output: true

Test question I got wrong, just tryna understand the answer.

Comment: So what did you do that was wrong?

Comment: That looks a lot like a regex expression. If I were you, I would simply create a regex expression from the given input, then try to match it with the other String. Now, it would be nice to see what you did.

Comment: You need to maintain a table to map the strings if your symbol is mapping to more than one elements...

Comment: For a regex , how would I set the + to equal any letter?

Comment: Something along the lines of ``` var regex = /^d{string1.length}"="[a-z]"$"[1-9]$/```

Comment: Can you post the code you attempted?

Answer (score 1):

The code below gives you your answer, although, it is a modifucation of the code above

```
function StringChallenge(str) {
  // code goes here
  let wordsArr = str.split(" ");

  function re(pattern) {
    let capture = 1;
    const source = pattern
      .replace(/([+*$])(?:\{(\d+)\})?/g, (match, rule, repeat = 3) => {
        switch (rule) {
          case "+":
            return "[a-z]";
          case "*":
            return `(.)\\${capture++}{${repeat - 1}}`;
          case "$":
            return "\\d";
        }
      })
      .replace(/(.+?)\1+/g, (match, capture) => {
        const rle = `(?:${capture}){${match.length / capture.length}}`;
        return rle.length < match.length ? rle : match;
      });
    return new RegExp(`^${source}$`);
  }

  function compare(pattern, input) {
    const result = re(pattern).test(input);
    return result;
  }
  return compare(wordsArr[0], wordsArr[1]);
}


console.log(StringChallenge("$**+*{2} 9mmmrrrkbb"));
console.log(StringChallenge("$**{2} ammmrrbb"));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by iterating over the pattern and keeping a pointer to where in the string we're checking right now. That way you can move the pointer more or less by what N is in `{N}` (defaulting to 3); In each case I simply return false if the character isn't in the allowed set, and for * I figure out how many times the current character should be repeated and check if the next `N` characters equal `input[x].repeat(N)` (the current character repeated N times).

You can definitely do this with regex as well, but I honestly feel like it would end up being more complicated due to the need to translate each character to a class or repeat match.

```js
function matchPattern(input, pattern) {
  let x = 0; //pointer to input string
  for(let i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
    switch(pattern[i]) {
      case '+':
        if(!'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.includes(input[x++])) return false;
        break;
      case '$':
        if(!'0123456789'.includes(input[x++])) return false;
        break;
      case '*':
        let repeatNum = 3;
        if(pattern[i+1] == '{' && pattern[i+3] == '}') repeatNum = +pattern[i+2];
        if(input[x].repeat(repeatNum) != input.slice(x,x+=repeatNum)) return false;
        break;
    }
  }
  return x >= input.length;
}

console.log(matchPattern("abcdehhhhhh", "+++++*"));
console.log(matchPattern("9mmmrrrkbb", "$**+*{2}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the pattern string into a regular expression with [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp) constructor, then use [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to compare against the input string:

```js
function re(pattern) {
  let capture = 1;

  const source = pattern.replace(
    /([+*$])(?:\{(\d+)\})?/g,
    (match, rule, repeat = 3) => {
      switch (rule) {
        case '+': return '[a-z]';
        case '*': return `(.)\\${capture++}{${repeat - 1}}`;
        case '$': return '\\d';
      }
    }
  );

  // the generated regular expression
  console.log(source);

  return new RegExp(`^${source}$`);
}

function compare(input, pattern) {
  const result = re(pattern).test(input);
  console.log(`'${input}' matches '${pattern}': ${result}`);
  return result;
}

compare('abcdehhhhhh', '+++++*');
compare('9mmmrrrkbb', '$**+*{2}');
```

Notice that the generated regular expressions can potentially be long and repetitive, so we can encode repeating rules within the source of the regular expression using [quantifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers#Types) as well:

```js
function re(pattern) {
  let capture = 1;

  const source = pattern.replace(
    /([+*$])(?:\{(\d+)\})?/g,
    (match, rule, repeat = 3) => {
      switch (rule) {
        case '+': return '[a-z]';
        case '*': return `(.)\\${capture++}{${repeat - 1}}`;
        case '$': return '\\d';
      }
    }
  ).replace(
    /(.+?)\1+/g,
    (match, capture) => {
      const rle = `(?:${capture}){${match.length / capture.length}}`;
      // only replace it if the rle is actually shorter
      return rle.length < match.length ? rle : match;
    }
  );

  // the generated regular expression
  console.log(source);

  return new RegExp(`^${source}$`);
}

function compare(input, pattern) {
  const result = re(pattern).test(input);
  console.log(`'${input}' matches '${pattern}': ${result}`);
  return result;
}

compare('abcdehhhhhh', '+++++*');
compare('9mmmrrrkbb', '$**+*{2}');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it using php

```
    <?php

/******
 * This is a Jawaker Assesment from Coderbyte.com
 * level HARD
 *
 * Task: StringChallenge(str)
 *
 *  Have the function StringChallenge(str) read str
 *  which will contain two strings separated by a space.
 *  The first string will consist of the following sets of characters: +, *, $, and {N} which is optional.
 *  The plus (+) character represents a single alphabetic character,
 *  the ($) character represents a number between 1-9,
 *  and the asterisk (*) represents a sequence of the same character of length 3 unless it is followed by {N}
 *  which represents how many characters should appear in the sequence where N will be at least 1.
 *  Your goal is to determine if the second string exactly matches the pattern of the first string in the input.
 *  For example: if str is "++*{5} jtggggg" then the second string in this case does match the pattern,
 *  so your program should return the string true.
 *  If the second string does not match the pattern your program should return the string false.
 *  Examples
 *  Input: "+++++* abcdehhhhhh"
 *  Output: false
 *  Input: "$**+*{2} 9mmmrrrkbb"
 *  Output: true
 *
*/

$str = "+++++***{2}+ abcdehhhhhhxxx"; //true
$str1 = "++*{4} 23ssss"; //true
$str2 = "++$$*++**{2} we23pppreeeeww"; //true
$str3 = "+++++* abcdehhhhhh"; //false
function StringChallenge($str)
{
    //First thing we do here is to sperate the two strings in one array.
    $exploded = explode(' ', $str);
    //We count the elements inside the array.
    $countExploded = count($exploded);
    //If it's two strings then we are good.
    if ($countExploded > 2) return false;
    $firstString = $exploded[0];
    $secondString = $exploded[1];
    //Then we seperate each character from each string into two arrays.
    $splitFirst = str_split($firstString);
    $splitSecond = str_split($secondString);
    //We loop inside the first array(first string where the pattren with this following logic)
    //$i is for looping inside the first string, $j for looping inside the second string
    //I solved this by making a point system and it goes like this:
    //I take each character from first string and check what it's.
    //If it's a (+) and it's a letter in the first character from second string then we can move to check the next character.
    //And we add 1 to each matching pattren with a character.
    // j for counting characters second string.
    $j = 0;

    //Point checker
    $pointCheck = 0;
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($splitFirst);$i++)
    {
        //To avoid "warning undefined array key"
        if ($i < count($splitFirst) && $i + 1 != count($splitFirst))
        {
            if ($splitFirst[$i] == '*')
            {

                //Check if '*' is not the last character.
                //Check if after the * there is a {  and Check if after the number there is a }

                if ($splitFirst[$i + 1] == '{' && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $splitFirst[$i + 2]) && $splitFirst[$i + 3] == '}')
                {
                    $number = $splitFirst[$i + 2];
                    $pointCheck = $pointCheck + $number;
                }
            }

            if ($splitFirst[$i] == '*' && $splitFirst[$i + 1] != '{')
            {
                $secondLetter = $j + 1;
                $thirdLetter = $j + 2;
                //Check if the $j is not the last character , this line of code to not fall in warning Undifinded Array;
                if ($thirdLetter < count($splitSecond))
                {
                    if ($splitSecond[$j] == $splitSecond[$secondLetter] && $splitSecond[$secondLetter] == $splitSecond[$thirdLetter])
                    {
                        $j = $j + 3;
                        $pointCheck = $pointCheck + 3;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($splitFirst[$i] == '+' && preg_match("/[a-z]/", $splitSecond[$j]))
        {
            $j++;
            $pointCheck++;
        }
        elseif ($splitFirst[$i] == '+' && !preg_match("/[a-z]/", $splitSecond[$j]))
        {
            $pointCheck++;
        }

        if ($splitFirst[$i] == '$' && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $splitSecond[$j]))
        {
            $j++;
            $pointCheck++;
        }
        elseif ($splitFirst[$i] == '$' && !preg_match('/[0-9]/', $splitSecond[$j]))
        {
            $pointCheck++;
        }
    }

    if (count($splitSecond) == $pointCheck)
    {
        return "true";
    }
    else
    {
        return "false";
    }
}

echo StringChallenge($str3);
```